# Is it possible to render Silverlight elements on top of a Web Browser control (in OOB mode)

Tags: silverlight, webbrowser-control, silverlight-oob

I would like to be able to hide and reveal Web Browser controls using other Silverlight elements and various transitions.

It appears that any Web Browser controls are always rendered last on the page. Is there any way to get other elements to render on top of the Web Browser?

### Here is a minimal XAML example to show the problem:

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="BrowserSilverlightApplication.MainPage"
    Width="640" Height="480">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <WebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser" Margin="16" Loaded="WebBrowser_Loaded"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="#447171DE" Margin="8" Stroke="Black" IsHitTestVisible="False" StrokeThickness="0">
            <Rectangle.Effect>
                <BlurEffect Radius="18"/>
            </Rectangle.Effect>
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: You really need to provide more detail, or rephrase your question. I'm deliberating between you wanting to put heaps on WB controls (as in, WebBrowser1's and 2's etc) on a WinForm with Silverlight, or inside silverlight. Then, on the other hand, i'm thinking maybe you want silverlight elements in a WB control? If i understand you correct, you want the WB control to render last, in which case I suggest you look into the Z-Order property on both your controls. I'm really taking a shot in the dark here because I'm not confident in my understanding of your question. Cheers.

Comment: Not sure I can make it any simpler than it is: I want to render Silverlight elements on top of a `WebBrowser` control. A single rectangle, with a blur effect, would do for starters (but it always renders under the `WebBrowser` control). Z-Order only affects elements where there are not already in the correct order and apparently has no effect on a WebBrowser control which seems to always be rendered last.

Comment: I understand your problem now, and have provided a solution with example application sample so you can try it out for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

With the release of Silverlight 4.0, the WebBrowser control was introduced. But, it was designed only to be used in an ‘Out Of Browser’ application. However, with the release of Silverlight 5, the control can also be used in an ‘In-browser” trusted application.

Since the introduction of the WebBrowser control in Silverlight, many developers have been using it to display HTML content inside the application. But, the major limitation is the “Airspace” issue.

In an application window each pixel within the windows belongs to exactly only one HWND, which constitutes the airspace for that HWND. The HWND can render only on those pixels which belongs to it.

In a typical Silverlight OOB application, there will be only one Silverlight-HWND. So, the entire pixels in the Silverlight application belong to this HWND and that constitutes the airspace for that.

But, in our scenario when we introduce a WebBrowser control in our Silverlight OOB application, the Airspace is shared by the HWND of the WebBrowser control. And that is known as Airspace issue.

The pixels on which the WebBrowser control resides will belong to the WebBrowser-HWND. So, Silverlight will not be able to render anything on the pixel which belongs to other HWND.

This problem is because; the WebBrowser control available in Silverlight is a wrapper around the “System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser” control. The other Silverlight control will not create a new window for itself; rather it will be created under a single HWND. The WebBrowser control is not a real Silverlight control, but a wrapper around Windows HTML control.  These native controls will create their own HWND.

Because of this, the WebBrowser control always overlaps other controls within the application. For example, when the page with the fixed header and scroll functionality are being used or when the WebBrowser control is placed under a menu control. There could be other instances.

By using the “WebBrowserBrush”, we can overcome this problem.

The WebBrowserBrush was introduced with the WebBrowser control, and they are designed to work together to display rich HTML content.

WebBrowserBrush is a type of Brush object which paints an area with HTML content. This HTML content is provided by a WebBrowser control. Just like the other brush types, you can use a WebBrowserBrush to fill a rectangle, geometry contents of path and much more.

So, how is this brush going to help us resolve this problem?

To overcome this problem, you can hide the WebBrowser and use a WebBrowserBrush to paint the area with HTML content from the WebBrowser. The WebBrowserBrush will paint the HTML content in the same layer as other control, and will allow other controls to be displayed above it. We can show the WebBrowser control when it is needed. The only thing which we need to consider is to find an appropriate event to handle this logic.

In the sample application below, I want my combobox list to render above the WebBrowser when open. I have used the ComboBox_DropDownChanged event to handle the logic. When the list is open, I hide the WebBrowser control and paint the area with the WebBrowserBrush. I then bring the control back when the list is closed.

```
> <UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1_WebBrowser.MainPage"    
> xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"    
> xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"    
> xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"    
> xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
> <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White"
> HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">        
> <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">    
> <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch">     
> <Grid.RowDefinitions>                     <RowDefinition Height="50"
> />                     <RowDefinition Height="50" />                  
> <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />                 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
> <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>                     <ColumnDefinition
> Width="*"/>                     <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>        
> </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>                                  <ComboBox
> Canvas.ZIndex="10" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="cbTestList"                   
> DropDownOpened="cbTestList_DropDownOpened"
> DropDownClosed="cbTestList_DropDownClosed" >                    
> <ComboBox.Items>                         <ComboBoxItem Content="--
> Select --" IsSelected="True"/>                         <ComboBoxItem
> Content="Text1"/>                         <ComboBoxItem
> Content="Text2"/>                         <ComboBoxItem
> Content="Text3"/>                         <ComboBoxItem
> Content="Text4"/>                         <ComboBoxItem
> Content="Text5"/>                         <ComboBoxItem
> Content="Text6"/>                         <ComboBoxItem
> Content="Text7"/>                         <ComboBoxItem
> Content="Text8"/>                         <ComboBoxItem
> Content="Text9"/>                         <ComboBoxItem
> Content="Text10"/>                         <ComboBoxItem
> Content="Text11"/>                         <ComboBoxItem
> Content="Text12"/>                         <ComboBoxItem
> Content="Text13"/>                         <ComboBoxItem
> Content="Text14"/>                         <ComboBoxItem
> Content="Text15"/>                     </ComboBox.Items>              
> </ComboBox>                                                           
> <WebBrowser x:Name="wb" Height="500" Width="800" Grid.Column="0"
> Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="2"                             
> Canvas.ZIndex="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"                       
> VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />                                 
> <TextBox x:Name="txtUrl" Margin="10" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"     
> Canvas.ZIndex="10"/>                   <Button Grid.Column="1"
> Grid.Row="1" Margin="10" Canvas.ZIndex="10" Content="Go"              
> Name="btnLoadContent" Click="btnLoadContent_Click" />                 
> <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Height="500" Width="800"
> Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="2"                             
> HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"                             
> VerticalAlignment="Stretch">                     <Rectangle.Fill>     
> <WebBrowserBrush SourceName="wb" x:Name="WBB1"/>                    
> </Rectangle.Fill>                 </Rectangle>             </Grid>    
> </Canvas>     </Grid> </UserControl>
```

Though we are able to overcome the problem using a WebBrowserBrush along with the WebBrowser control, we still have a couple of limitations which we need to consider.

1.The user cannot interact with the WebBrowserBrush.

2.The changes in the WebBrowser control will not reflect automatically unless redrawn.

This is a simple workaround to the problem and it will work if designed properly, considering the limitation we have.